# How can I add a special Mongo expression to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

So I'm aware how I should add any regular string/object to a JSON object - however, I need to add the following Mongo command to my JSON object:

```
$set : { "author" : req.body.name }
```

As you can see, it's not as simple as just doing:

```
myJsonObject.author = "$set..." etc.
```

Sorry if this is a dupe question - this isn't the easiest subject to Google without tons of unrelated answers popping up.

The reason I need to know this because I want to be able to build a JSON object based on what the user has changed in the form. So a new problem I have encountered is that even if I can build the JSON object with multiple items to change, MongoDB only updates the last item in the object. My example JSON object is here:

```
updateItem = {
    $set : { "name" : "Squid bonobo" },
    $set : { "author" : "Mardy Bum" }
};
```

and the snippet of code which issues the update command is as follows:

```
updateData.update(searchItem, updateItem, false, true, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        db.close();
    });
```

I found this solution at [the following git site](https://gist.github.com/sym3tri/858142).

Can anybody help with either of these questions?

Thanks for your help :)

Cameron

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking here. Are you trying to add to your mongodb straight from the json object that you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to form your `JSON` in the below structure:

```
updateItem = {
    $set : { "name":"Squid bonobo","author":"Mardy Bum"}
}
```

Javascript Objects *can* be declared with duplicate keys/properties, but their values get over-written, with the latest bound value for the `key`, in any order.

Here, `$set` is a key/property which has been set twice to the same object referenced by the variable `updateItem`, hence only one value, that is last encountered, will be associated to the `key`. In this case, the value that takes precedence is:

```
$set:{ "author":"Mardy Bum" }
```

and the final query that gets executed becomes,

```
updateItem = {
    $set : { "author" : "Mardy Bum" }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can confirm this worked for me. However, how could I go about building the query inside the $set parameters? It will be different every time the function is called, so it needs to be changeable. For example, how could I add another field and entry, e.g. "price" : "12.99". Thanks :)

Comment: EDIT: I did it by simply creating a JSON object before ever calling the $set stuff, and then adding in the ojbect once I'd checked if any changes had been made. Code was simply: updateItem = {
        $set : editItems
    };